# Matlab Symbolic expression creates overflow

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

I am using Matlab symbolic toolbox to create a function of high complexity. This function is then written to a .m-file (using `matlabFunction`). For some reason, after simplifying the function, the function is returned on a form that looks like `fun = (A*1.329834759483753e310 + B*5.873798798237459e305 + ...)*7.577619127319697e-320`, where `A` and `B` are functions of my variables (too complex to repeat here). That is, all the terms within the parenthesis are in the order of about 1e280 to 1e300. The problems arises when the exponents become larger than about 1.79e308, as this causes an overflow for doubles (when calling the generated .m-function). The real size of the function is nowhere close to create an overflow, but this way of expressing the function does. This would be solved if the simplify function multiplied the 1e-320 into the parenthesis, but for some reason it doesn't.

Any idea why the symbolic toolbox chooses to represent my function this way?

I have found that I can call call `expand(fun)` to multiply 1e-320 into the parenthesis. The resulting expression then has exponents with the expected sizes (in the range -1 to -30) but I would prefer to know the reason why the expression looks like this in the first place, and if there are better options than calling `expand` to avoid the problem. Besides, calling `expand` seems to create a more complex function than the one I have, and I am trying to obtain a function that evaluates very fast here.

Comment: Symbolic math always tries to represent your floating-point numbers exactly. If you start from 2.3/5.7, after a few matrix multiplications and square roots you'll have very fancy floats, which will be quite difficult to represent exactly. This often leads to huge integer/integer literal constants in symbolic functions, your problem might be related. If all else fail, you might also try leaving those coefficients symbolic as well (if possible), and entering those into your numerical function in the end.

Comment: @AndrasDeak You are right about floats being the cause of this. Unfortunately, leaving these coefficients symbolic is not an option, as this makes the computations too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large exponent multipliers are probably due to some floats in the formula. Try to avoid them and use rationals (1/2 instead of 0.5).

The best reason I've read is [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13861-matlabfunction-produces-file-with-insufficient-precision):

> The floating point numbers tend to get converted to rational numbers, which usually involves multiplying by 2^53 and then factoring out the gcd from the top and bottom of the ratio. Square such a value and you are working with numbers on the order of 2^100... and so on.

Comment: You are right about the floats being the cause of this. I tried replacing the floats with rational approximations (by using rat()), but it seems like these rationals are also too complex, as the problem remains.

Comment: You may split the formula and see which part causes such complexity. Also, you can put a bounty on your question as it did not attract that much attention. You would have some more input on your problem.